# Copy map/multimap keys to vector or set

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I have written below code to convert keys in `map` or `multimap` to `set`:

```
template<typename STLContainer>
inline auto CopyContanerKeyToSet(const STLContainer& cont)
{
    std::set<decltype(cont.begin()->first)> lset;
    std::transform(cont.begin(),cont.end(),std::inserter(lset,lset.end()),[](const  auto it) { return it.first;});
    return lset
}
```

Now there is requirement that sometimes I need to convert keys into `vector` as well. So I just want to know how to write template function that can accept `vector` or `set` as template argument and after that create that container accordingly.

Comment: Just add another template type that you specify when you call the function?

Comment: i don't want to pass complete type like std::vector<std::string> as i want function to deduce std::string itself so want to know how to pass only std::vector

Comment: And how you want to discriminate between those overloads?

Comment: no discrimination when user passed set then set of keys when user pass vector then vector of keys should be returned

Comment: What? You pass a `map` or `multimap`, how do you want to guess whether to return `vector` or `set`? You have only one parameter.

Comment: I have given example of code where i have converted map/multimap keys to set and i was asking how to write generic function to convert that to set or vector of keys

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Sorry. I misunderstood you. I somehow thought you want to deduce the result type only based on the function parameters.

Answer (score 2):

We can solve this with a *Template template parameter*.  This allows us to specify just the main type without specifying the template type of that type.  Doing that gives us

```
template< template<typename ...> class OutputContainer, typename STLContainer>
inline auto CopyContanerKeyToSet(const STLContainer& cont)
{
    OutputContainer<typename STLContainer::key_type> lset;
    std::transform(cont.begin(),cont.end(),std::inserter(lset,lset.end()),[](const  auto it) { return it.first;});
    return lset;
}
```

And then we can use that with something like this

```
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> foo{ {"this", 1}, {"second", 1} };
    auto output = CopyContanerKeyToSet<std::vector>(foo);
    for (const auto& e : output)
        std::cout << e << " ";
}
```

Which gives us

```
second this
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93ece05ac6edb639)</kbd>

---

I also changed `<decltype(cont.begin()->first)>` to `<typename STLContainer::key_type>` as `value_type` of the `map`/`multimap` has a `const key_type` for the `std::pair` which we do not want for the `vector`/`set`.

Comment: @Kapil Sorry about that.  I had just copied your code assuming it worked.  I've updated it now.

Comment: @Kapil No problem.  Glad to help.